# EFCore can't understand many to many

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I get the following error:
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Application.Computers' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property from the model.

My code for Computer.cs

```
public int Id { get; private set; }
/* some properties */
public ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
```

And Application.cs

```
public int Id { get; private set; }
/* some properties */
public ICollection<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
```

I'm new to EF and EFCore, so I don't know if this is the way to make many to many relationships. If so, what am I doing wrong? Else how can I manually configure the relationship?

Comment: Take a look at [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) - **Many-to-many** section of the documentation

Comment: Thanks, I found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#other-relationship-patterns) says it all:
Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table **are not yet supported**. 

However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.